# Error message "Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference"

Tags: php, reference, strict

```
$el = array_shift($instance->find(..))
```

The above code somehow reports the strict standards warning, but this will not:

```
function get_arr(){
    return array(1, 2);
}
$el = array_shift(get_arr());
```

So when will it report the warning anyway?

Comment: What does $instance->find(..) return?

Comment: Here is the solution: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848295/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference-error

Comment: I think the examples (or logic) might be the wrong way round in the question, since the 2nd example (`get_arr()` function) **does** produce the strict standards notice (tested PHP 5.2 and PHP 5.5).

Answer (score 93):

Consider the following code:

```
error_reporting(E_STRICT);
class test {
    function test_arr(&$a) {
        var_dump($a);
    }
    function get_arr() {
        return array(1, 2);
    }
}

$t = new test;
$t->test_arr($t->get_arr());
```

This will generate the following output:

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in `test.php` on line 14
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
}
```

The reason? The `test::get_arr()` method is not a variable and under strict mode this will generate a warning. This behavior is extremely non-intuitive as the `get_arr()` method *returns* an array value.

To get around this error in strict mode, either change the signature of the method so it doesn't use a reference:

```
function test_arr($a) {
    var_dump($a);
}
```

Since you can't change the signature of `array_shift` you can also use an intermediate variable:

```
$inter = get_arr();
$el = array_shift($inter);
```

Comment: @user198729: I was looking for an explanation or fix too, and found you can use current() for the first item. Alas end() doesn't work for the last since it "advances the internal pointer to the last element". current(array_reverse(somefunction())) works (yes, it's silly)

Comment: I like the `current()` workaround. In fact, a lot of times I find myself using `array_shift()` what I really want is `current()`, but that could be just me.

Comment: Using `current` makes the assumption that the array pointer is at the first element. It may be a valid assumption in most cases, but one to watch out for.

Comment: @cbuckley - very true - which is why one should use `reset()` instead of `current()` to get the first element.  `reset()` will reset the internal array pointer *and* return the first element of the array.

Comment: @leepowers Of course, then there'd be the same issue as `array_shift()` in that it expects a reference to modify :-)

Comment: @user198729 You can avoid the `$intermediate` value by using an extra pair of parenthesis. `$el = array_shift( ( get_arr() ) );`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848295/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference-error#comment51192476_9848317

Comment: @Chloe This is the most brilliant solution I have seen for keeping the code simple!! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

`$instance->find()` returns a reference to a variable.

You get the report when you are trying to use this reference as an argument to a function, without storing it in a variable first.

This helps preventing memory leaks and will probably become an error in the next PHP versions.

Your second code block would throw an error if it wrote like (note the `&` in the function signature):

```
function &get_arr(){
    return array(1, 2);
}
$el = array_shift(get_arr());
```

So a quick (and not so nice) fix would be:

```
$el = array_shift($tmp = $instance->find(..));
```

Basically, you do an assignment to a temporary variable first and send the variable as an argument.

Comment: It should work now (checked it). In order to return reference you have to declare it at method signature, not return statement (my fault).

Comment: No,I can't change the signature.@pygorex1's intermediate variable can solve this,but it looks redundant,doesn't it?

Comment: I know you can't change the signature, just explained how it happens. You **have** to use temporary (=intermediate) variable, but you can do it in the same line. Look at my second code snippet.

Comment: I tried your second snippet,not working.It only works in a separate line

Comment: Indeed. An assignment *returns the assigned value*. `array_shift($tmp = $instance->find(..))` assigns the value of `$instance->find(..)` to `$tmp` and then passes the *value of the assignment* to `array_shift()` -- which is not the same thing as passing `$tmp` itself, so is no better than the original situation without the assignment.

Answer (score 6):

The cause of the error is the use of the internal PHP programming data structures function, array_shift() [php.net/end].

The function takes an array as a parameter. Although an ampersand is indicated in the prototype of `array_shift()` in the manual", there isn't any cautionary documentation following in the extended definition of that function, nor is there any apparent explanation that the parameter is in fact passed by reference.

Perhaps this is /understood/. I did not understand, however, so it was difficult for me to detect the cause of the error.

Reproduce code:

```
function get_arr()
{
    return array(1, 2);
}
$array = get_arr();
$el = array_shift($array);
```

Answer (score 3):

The second snippet doesn't work either and that's why.

`array_shift` is a modifier function, that changes its argument. Therefore it expects its parameter to be a reference, and you cannot reference something that is not a variable. See Rasmus' explanations here: [Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48937)

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
$monthly_index = array_shift(unpack('H*', date('m/Y')));
```

Need to be changed into:

```
$date_time = date('m/Y');
$unpack = unpack('H*', $date_time);
array_shift($unpack);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in obvious cases like that, you can always tell PHP to suppress messages by using "@" in front of the function.

```
$monthly_index = @array_shift(unpack('H*', date('m/Y')));
```

It may not be one of the best programming practices to suppress **all** errors this way, but in certain cases (like this one) it comes handy and is acceptable.

As result, I am sure your friend 'system administrator'  will be pleased with a less polluted `error.log`.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this answer, but the presented solution DOES work and it IS a PHP standard technique. Really disappointing... Next time I might no answer a question anymore... :(

Comment: I would assume it was because suppressing the error message does not fix the problem with the code. What will you do when this type of error changes from E_STRICT to E_ERROR in a future PHP release and your code now does not run, and also does not produce any errors/output?

Comment: @TinoDidriksen, I understand and agree with the reasons to advise against some "bad habits", especially for the new generations. However, a resource exists to be used when (and if) it is safe to use and applicable to the proposed context. If the error suppressor "@" was to be abolished, it would have been removed from the language itself. Same as "eval" (it may be evil, but it has its purposes). What I am against is not about the usage of some resources but the generalization of an advice. In specific for the proposed case, it wouldn't be of any harm to use it, not even for debugging purposes.