# Only variables should be passed by reference - socket_select()

Tags: php, sockets

I have a function in my class which utilizes the socket_select() function and I noticed that it's throwing this warning:

```
Strict Standards: *Only variables should be passed by reference*
```

This is how I'm using it, and yes, I did read the "Example #1 Using NULL with socket_select()" in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php)

```
$read = array($this->socket);
$write = NULL;
$except = NULL;

socket_select($read, $write, $except, 0, $this->socket_timeout);
```

This results in a big error spam when calling the function inside a while loop. Of course, I can suppress the E_STRICT errors, but I would like to know what's the exact issue here. My PHP version is **5.3.5**

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact line that triggers the error?

Comment: socket_select accepts only array did you try array(NULL) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly it doesn't like a NULL reference?

I would try:

```
$read = array($this->socket);
$write = array();
$except = array();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with assigning the variable earlier with this data `$null=null;` and using after that inside the `socket_select($read, $null, $null, $tv_sec = 5)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).