# Pass by reference variable warning in end()

Tags: php, arrays

How do you remove this warning?

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in

I have code that gets unique values from a multidimensional array and then gets the last index.

```
$catchColors[]= array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $totalRows; $i++) {
    $catchColors[$i] = $postData[$i]['ColorID'];
}

$result = array_unique($catchColors);
print_r($result);

print end(array_keys($result));
```

it still returns the value, but how do I remove the warning?

Comment: shouldn't it be `$catchColors = array();` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the parameter for the function [`end`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) will be passed by reference. Thus, it can't be a return of another function, it should be, as the notice says, an actual variable.

So, a solution is to create a temporary variable to hold the array of the keys, and then execute `end` in that array.

```
$keys = array_keys($result);
print end($keys);
```

Comment: Agreed. So why doesn't: "print end(($keys =  array_keys($result)));" avoid the warning?  Isn't the first parameter now a variable?