# php Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in "use"

Tags: php, standards, php-5.3, strict

While working I met this annoying message

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in G:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\ZendSkeletonApplication\module\Admission\src\Admission\Controller\AdmissionController.php on line 107
```

My code

```
$consoldatedCities = '';

array_walk_recursive(
    $StateCityHash,
    function($cityName, $cityId) use (&$consoldatedCities) {
        $consoldatedCities[$cityId] = $cityName;
    }
); // line 107
```

This is to convert multidimensional array into simple array .

But the code works as I expected. Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Comment: No Repro: https://3v4l.org/mEI9a#v5.3.29

Answer (score 0):

Here http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php it says that "There is no reference sign on a function call - only on function definitions." Try removing the '&' from your function call code there and see if that gets rid of the message.

---Edit---

Looking at this thread here ["Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848295/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference-error)

you could try saving your callback function into a variable before passing it to the array walk function:

```
$consoldatedCities=array();

$callbackFcn= 
   function($cityName,$cityId) use(&$consoldatedCities)
   {
      $consoldatedCities[$cityId] = $cityName; 
   };

array_walk_recursive($StateCityHash, $callbackFcn);
```

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response. If i remove the '&' from function call the '$consoldatedCities' will be empty

Comment: Thanks,Still I am getting the same error in this line  `array_walk_recursive($StateCityHash, $callbackFcn);` . here we have just assigned the same function in `$callbackFcn`, so it also causing same error.I think that i have to revert and to do something with `foreach`.