# Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in... on line 777

Tags: php

I get an error on some pages of my website:

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in
>   /home/... on line 777

here is this line:

```
$arg_list = $this->_compile_arg_list('function', $tag_command, $attrs, $_cache_attrs='');
```

What should I change?
Any help is appreciated.

The problem solved, thanks.

Comment: `$_cache_attrs=''` looks suspicious but I've never used this function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VYd26.png) toolbar button—I've done it for you this time.

Comment: You might want to add the signature of the called method. However it's the first or fourth argument that causes you trouble.

Comment: `$_cache_attrs=''` is most likely a plain typo.

Comment: is this some newly present in PHP 5.4+? We all like the PHP upgrades so much...

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9848295/684229

Comment: If the problem is solved, please ask the good comment to make an answer, and accept it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

function foo(&$a){
}

$a = 33;
foo($a); // OK

foo(33); // Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference
```

So fix your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a value in a function call that expects a variable by reference, if you need a default behavior you can set that up in the function itself or before calling it.

```
$_cache_attrs = '';
$arg_list = $this->_compile_arg_list('function', $tag_command, $attrs, $_cache_attrs);
```

Comment: @user3062493 Feel free to accept an answer if it works and fits your question

Answer (score 0):

maybe `'function'` should be callable..

```
$function = function() { };
$arg_list = $this->_compile_arg_list(
    $function,
    $tag_command,
    $attrs,
    $_cache_attrs=''
);
```