# Strict Standards trouble

Tags: php, strict

I have trouble with error

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\tanthanh\includes\cls_template.php on line 406"

And line 406 in cls_template file

```
$tag_sel = array_shift(explode(' ', $tag));
switch ($tag_sel)
```

What do I need to correct?

Comment: `array_shift()` must write back to an array variable, so you need to store the results of the `explode()` in a variable and pass that instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848295/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference-error)