# Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in... - error line

Tags: php, arrays, variables, standards, strict

I have error like this:

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /file.php in line 100

In file.php line look like this:

```
foreach($filelist as $value => $file) {
    // ABOVE LINE IS LINE 100
    if(in_array(end(explode(".", $file)), $extensions)&&is_file($dir.$file)) { $c++; }
    if(IsSet($_GET['start'])) {
        $nav = $_GET['start'];
    } else {
        $nav = "0";
    }
    if(($c > $nav) && ($c < $nav+($pagerows+1))) {
        $link = $dir . $file;
        $hlink = $http . $file;
        $ext = explode(".", $file);
        if(in_array(end($ext), $extensions)&&is_file($link)) {
            $p++;
            if(file_exists($link)) {
                list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($link);
                if($height > SMALL_IMAGE_HEIGHT) {
                    $imageheight = SMALL_IMAGE_HEIGHT;
                } else {
                    $imageheight = $height;
                }
```

Could you help me? I found topics like this but noon have code like my code.

Comment: Hi, I've improved formatting of the question (the comment marking the line 100 wasn't actually visible!) Still, I suggest you to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and ask questions in accord to this guideline. The nice thing is, once you start to minimize the code that reproduces the problem, it is more likely that you find the source of the problem for yourself. Also, you should site "topics like this" so that we can suggest ones you overlooked. Best regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848295/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference-error)

Answer (score 0):

`end` accepts its parameter by reference, because it modifies the array. I. e. it moves the array iterator to the last element and returns the last element. That's why you get the warning. You can remove it, if you simply replace the line that produces the error:

```
if(in_array(end(explode(".", $file)), $extensions)&&is_file($dir.$file)) { $c++; }
```

Replace with:

```
$ext = explode(".", $file); 
if(in_array(end($ext), $extensions)&&is_file($dir.$file)) { $c++; }
```

Like you did in a later part of your code.

Then you could also delete line 105 (`$ext = explode(".", $file);`), but you don't have to.

Comment: so `if(in_array(end(explode(".", $file)),` change to `if(in_array(end($tmp = explode(".", $file)),` ?

Comment: exactly. Or you could use `$ext`, like you did later in your code.

Comment: I change to `if(in_array(end($ext = explode(".", $file)), $extensions)&&is_file($dir.$file)) { $c++; }`
 and error still shown

Comment: My bad. I was sure that the assignment would work like this, but apparently it does not. I'll edit the answer to correct it.

Comment: The answer should be correct now. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You forgot about ";" but yes, it's works, thank you!

Comment: @gold1s if this answers your question, please don't forget to accept it by clicking the tick on the left

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use something better to get the extension like this

```
$ext = strrchr($file, ".");
```

The only difference is this keeps the `.` so if `$file` is `somefile.txt` it return `.txt`  which if you want to get rid of you could always do this

```
$ext = ltrim(strrchr($file, "."), '.');
```

For reference

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php

> **strrchr** — Find the last occurrence of a character in a string.
>
> **string** strrchr ( **string** $haystack , **mixed** $needle )
>
> This function returns the portion of haystack which starts at the last occurrence of needle and goes until the end of haystack.

So it just finds the last `.` and return that and everything after, then `ltrim` is just "left" trim.

P.S. I really dislike using explode for getting the extension, it's one of my pet peeves.

So for your particular case I would:

```
foreach($filelist as $value => $file) {
    $ext = ltrim(strrchr($file, "."), '.');
    if(in_array($ext, $extensions) && is_file($dir.$file)) { $c++; } 

    if(isset($_GET['start'])) { $nav = $_GET['start']; } else { $nav = "0"; }
    if(($c > $nav)&&($c < $nav+($pagerows+1))) {
    $link = $dir . $file;
    $hlink = $http . $file;
      
    //$ext = explode(".", $file); we've already done this no need to do it again
```

This way, you get the extension one time, you don't create an array for it `explode`, you don't move the array pointer to the end of the array `end` and that's about it.

**UPDATE**

You can compare these two using `microtime` to see which is faster, they are both really fast so we have to do about 100k iterations to test it, like this:

```
$filename = "filename.php";

$start = microtime(true);

for($i=0; $i<=100000; $i++){
    $v=explode(".", $filename);
    $ext1 = end($v);
}

echo "1. ext='$ext1' Complete ".number_format((microtime(true) - $start), 4).PHP_EOL;

$start = microtime(true);

for($i=0; $i<=100000; $i++){
    $ext2 = ltrim(strrchr($filename, '.'), '.');
    
}

echo "2. ext='$ext2' Complete ".number_format((microtime(true) - $start), 4).PHP_EOL;
```

Outputs

```
 1. ext='php' Complete 0.0178
 2. ext='php' Complete 0.0098
 ----------------------------
 1. ext='php' Complete 0.0237
 2. ext='php' Complete 0.0125
 ---------------------------
 1. ext='php' Complete 0.0252
 2. ext='php' Complete 0.0098
 ---------------------------
 1. ext='php' Complete 0.0190
 2. ext='php' Complete 0.0102
```

You can test it [here online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e256075d4a7d66eac4b9c310f94b114d2243ab11)

One thing is clear, it's almost 2x faster, not that it matters much in this case.  But, it never hurts to check these things.  Both give equivalent results, but `strrchr` is easier to read, well if you know what the function does anyway.  It's kind of an obscure function but it basically means **str**ing **r**ight **ch**a**r**acter.

Cheers.

Comment: So could you write to me,  what should I replace in my code?