# CUTENEWS.RU - Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in

Tags: php

I have a problem with this code, any help?

```php
$var = reset($sql -> select(array(
  'table' => 'news',
  'join' => array('table' => 'story', 'where' => 'id = post_id'),
  'where' => array("id = $id", 'or', "url = $id")
)));
```

Error:

> ```
> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in
>
> $query = reset(  
>     $sql->select(array(  
>         'table'     => 'news',  
>         'where'     => $where  
> )));   
> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in
> ```

Comment: Which library do you use? What type is $sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9848317/5533075).

`reset()` function is waiting for a variable reference, instead you are passing it a **function result**.

For more info see [php reset docs](http://www.php.net/reset)

You can, extract the result of the function and then pass it to `reset()` as shown below.

```
$select = $sql -> select(array(
  'table' => 'news',
  'join' => array('table' => 'story', 'where' => 'id = post_id'),
  'where' => array("id = $id", 'or', "url = $id")
))
$var = reset($select);
```

Then the other one:

```
$select1 = $sql->select(array(
             'table'      => 'news',
             'where'      => $where
            ));
$query = reset($select1);
```

---

**PHP live demo**

- [correct](https://ideone.com/mNRkta)
- [incorrect](https://ideone.com/sj0f1D)