# Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in

Tags: php, variables, reference

I am trying to work on a forgot password system. I have no clue why I am getting this error, I've rechecked the code almost five times. Any help would be wonderful.

by the way, this is Exception.

> Error- Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\core\init.php on line 8

**recover.php**

```
echo $current_file = end(explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));
```

Comment: It's telling you the problem. It sounds like your passing something other than a variable by reference. Then, it tells you `line 8` of `recover.php`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 3):

This error seems to be because you are passing in a value to `explode()` rather than a variable, try this:

```
$var = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$current_file = end(explode('/', $var));
```

Comment: sorry, that didn't help at all. I've still got the error, thanks though.

Comment: It’s `end` that expects a reference as it changes the internal array value pointer.

Comment: Gumbo is right. Explode the thing into a variable and then send the variable to end.

Answer (score 2):

As explained very well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19829414/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference-in-functions-php), the PHP *end()* method waits for a *variable reference* to work correctly. What you have to do is simply give a variable reference instead of a plain value.

```
$var = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
$exploded = explode('/', $var);
$current_file = end($exploded);
```