# Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in functions.php on line 1505

Tags: php, reference

The error first appears with the call to `JB_do_house_keeping()`. This function gets called at every request!

```
JBPlug_do_callback('jb_init', $A=false);  // **ERROR HERE**

define ('JB_INIT_COMPLETED', true);
```

================================

Then also with `JB_save_session()`:

```
JBPLUG_do_callback('house_keeping_critical_section', $A = false); // **ERROR HERE**
```

Please help! I am stuck here: I am a basic coder trying something new...

Comment: Can we see the code for `JBPLUG_do_callback()`? I'd guess it's something like `function JBPLUG_do_callback(&$a, $b), where the first argument shouldn't have an `&` as a prefix.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to pass information to a function in PHP:

- as a value (e.g. `false`, `48`, `'foobar'`)
- as a [reference to a variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) (e.g. `$a`)

Functions define how they want to receive their arguments. If they expect to receive it as a reference, that means that the changes the function makes to the variable will have an effect in the scope where the function was called.

If you provide a value where the function is expecting a reference, the function won't properly do what you expect.

For instance, `array_splice` expects its first argument to be a reference, so that you can get the modifications made to the array. But imagine if you did this:

```
array_splice(array('foo', 'bar'), 1);
```

You've passed in a value, not a reference. The code that called your function can't get the modified array, because `array_splice` doesn't return it.  The correct way is like this:

```
$array = array('foo', 'bar');
array_splice($array, 1);
echo count($array); // echoes 1
```

This is because `array_splice` takes a reference, and so modifies a variable.

In your case, you're doing this:

```
JBPlug_do_callback('jb_init', $A=false);
```

Presumably, `JBPlug_do_callback` is expecting a reference as its second argument. You are providing a value (`=` returns a value). It may make no difference to what the function does, but technically it's a breach of PHP's rules. (That's why it's a "strict standards" error: it may well not have a bad effect, but it's technically invalid.)

You can solve this, again, simply by providing what PHP wants: a variable:

```
$A = false;
JBPlug_do_callback('jb_init', $A);
```