# Variable reference error in PHP

Tags: php

I have upgraded PHP from v5.3 to v5.4 and I am now getting the following error:

> Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

Code:

```
$filename = array_pop(explode("/", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));
```

How to fix this?

Comment: try `$filename_arr = explode("/", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']); $filename = array_pop($filename_arr);`

Comment: `array_pop` expects a variable as it tries to remove the last item from it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breaking the code apart would resolve the error

```
$filename = explode("/", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
$filename = array_pop($filename);

echo $filename ;
```

[Demo Break Apart](http://codepad.org/O4YgP9bt)