# How to fix "Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference"?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Can someone please help me with these 4 lines of code. I been trying to read how to fix this error but I'm not very familiar with php that much yet.

```
$currentFile = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
$img = array_pop(explode("/", $currentFile));
$fileName = basename($img, ".php").PHP_EOL;
echo $fileName;
```

This script finds the current $.php name and spits it out. It also cuts the location of the file and the extension as well... leaving just the fileName.

How would I write these 4 lines of code to not throw that Strict Standard error

Comment: Try moving `explode(...)` into a variable.

Comment: Don't know how, or where to put it. I know, I'm bad... sorry!

Comment: `$path = explode("/", $currentFile);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 2):

Just add a varible.

```
$currentFile = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
$ret = explode("/", $currentFile);
$img = array_pop($ret);
$fileName = basename($img, ".php").PHP_EOL;
echo $fileName;
```

But you could just use `basename` only, the below code will give you same result:

```
$fileName = basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"], ".php").PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Wow, how do you guys know all this. 

Thanks, and also thanks for shortening the code.