# PHP Strict Standards on line with variable

Tags: string, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Annoying PHP error: “Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117106/annoying-php-error-strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-refere)

I have this line of code,

```
$extension=end(explode(".", $srcName));
```

when I fun my function I get

> PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference in

I am not sure how to solve this

Comment: Related: [Parentheses altering semantics of function call result](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6726589/367456)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function [`end()`](http://php.net/end) requires a variable to be passed-by-reference and passing the return-value of a function doesn't acheive this. You'll need to use two lines to accomplish this:

```
$exploded = explode(".", $srcName);
$extension = end($exploded);
```

If you're simply trying to get a file-extension, you could also use [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr) and [`strrpos()`](http://php.net/strrpos) to do it in one line:

```
$extension = substr($srcName, strrpos($srcName, '.'));
```

Or, if you know the number of `.`'s that appear in the string, say it's only 1, you can use `list()` (but this won't work if there is a dynamic number of `.`'s:

```
list(,$extension) = explode('.', $srcName);
```

Comment: *Pssst:* If it's about the file-extension, better link a question that is specifically about it. Like: [How to extract a file extension in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/173868/367456)

Comment: Billiant simple solution, makes sense and really helped me out there, thanks nefurniturey