# Error : Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: strict

With this code:

```
GetTableProp($tbl, $fld=array(), $typ=array(), $def=array());
```

I received an error on this line:

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php 5.+, You should define the type of each varibale.

For example:

```
function Gettable(int $n)
{
   //the code is here
}
```

If you want to disable the strict standards in the server, you have to desactivate error reporting in php.ini

error_reporting = E_Error