# Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in functions.php

Tags: php, standards, strict

I'm a bit confused by the error I am getting.

The error is:

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in
>   functions.php

The line in reference is:

```
$action = array_pop($a = explode('?', $action)); // strip parameters
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$a= explode('?',$action);
$action = array_pop($a);
```

By the way, what is `$action`?

Answer (score 0):

`array_pop` the only parameter is an array passed by reference. The return value of `explode("?", $action)` does not have any reference.

You should store the return value to a variable first:

```
$arr = explode('?',$action);
$action = array_pop($arr);
```

The following things can be passed by reference:

- **Variables**, i.e. foo($a)
- **New statements**, i.e. foo(new foobar())
- **References returned from functions**

[Passing by Reference in PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Answer (score 0):

> $action = array_pop($a = explode('?', $action));  ///Wrong
>
> $action = array_pop($a = (explode('?', $action)));  ///Right
>
> Makesure you put explode in brackets like (explode()), that's it..