# Strict Standards php error

Tags: php

I have a small issue with my script.

I'm getting Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in

```
if( $checkDNS && ($domain = end(explode('@',$email, 2))) )
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [PHP manual](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php):

> This array is passed by reference because it is modified by the function. This means you must pass it a real variable and not a function returning an array because only actual variables may be passed by reference.

So you must use a variable in the end function:

```
$domain = explode('@',$email, 2);
if( $checkDNS && ($domain = end($domain)) )
```

Answer (score 2):

From the manual:

```
mixed end ( array &$array )
```

`end` takes the array by reference and move the internal pointer. Your array is the function output, so its unable to correctly modify the array by reference.

Answer (score 0):

Like the message says, end expects a variable because its parameter is a reference.

But since PHP 5.4 you can dereference arrays like that:

```
$domain = explode('@',$email, 2)[1];
```

Assuming that $email always contains `@`. You should assure that beforehand, otherwise end(...) would give you unexpected results too.