# How do I avoid error - Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php

I am recieving the following error

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\wamp\www\dragdrop\newhotel\reservation\ajax\tips.php on line 8

Line 8 is

```
$img=mysql_real_escape_string(end(explode('/',$_POST['img'])));
```

I'm a newbie please help me..

Comment: You can edit your question rather than adding a comment, but thanks for the comment

Comment: I think [basename](http://php.net/basename) would suit you better

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 1):

Explode is a function so you can't pass it to end.  Use an intermediate variable.

```
$List = explode('/',$_POST['img']);
$img=mysql_real_escape_string(end($List));
```

Should work

Comment: You should give me an upvote as thanks, and when you can if it works select my answer as the accpeted answer by clicking the tick under the score.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing a variable, you are passing an array directly.

http://php.net/manual/de/function.end.php

```
$var = explode('/',$_POST['img']);
$var = end($var);
$img = mysql_real_escape_string($var);
```