# Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in array

Tags: php, arrays, strict

```
$name = substr($name, 0, -strlen($ext)) . "_medium." . end(explode('.',$name));
```

the above code report strick standard warning, the small script as below:

```
  function medium($name) {
    $ext = strrchr($name, '.');
    if($ext !== false) {
        $name = substr($name, 0, -strlen($ext)) . "_medium." . end(explode('.',$name));
    }
    return $name;
  }

  function thumb($name) {
    $ext = strrchr($name, '.');
    if($ext !== false) {
        $name = substr($name, 0, -strlen($ext)) . "_thumb." . end(explode('.',$name));
    }
    return $name;
  }

  function name_remove($name) {
    $name = str_replace("_medium", "", $name);
    $name = str_replace("_thumb", "", $name);
    return $name;
  }
```

how can i fix this warning? need help :)

Comment: `end()` takes the array by reference, only VARIABLES may be passed by reference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 0):

```
$blocks = explode('.',$name);
$name = substr($name, 0, -strlen($ext)) . "_medium." . end($blocks);
```

But why not use [pathinfo()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

Answer (score 0):

Change your error reporting to `30719`.