# Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php, standards, strict

My PHP script is displaying an error:

> ```
> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\....*.php on line 551
> ```

The code is below:

```
function trinity_premissions()
{
        global $ACC_PDO, $WEB_PDO, $a_user, $db_translation;

        $end = false;

        $res = $WEB_PDO->prepare("SELECT acc_login, gmlevel FROM `accounts_more` WHERE UPPER(acc_login) = :acc");
/* 551 */$res->bindParam(':acc', strtoupper($a_user[$db_translation['login']]), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $res->execute();

        if ($res->rowCount() == 1)
        {
                $s2 = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                if ($s2['gmlevel']<>'')
                {
                        return $s2['gmlevel'];
                }
        }
        unset($res);
}
```

I don't know what the problem is. Can anyone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 2):

Your second parameter 'strtoupper($a_user[$db_translation['login']])' must be a reference to a variable.

doc : [Ref to bindparam](http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

the 'mixed &$variable' in the doc say that it must be a reference (it's the '&')

you can create a variable, and  put the result of 'strtoupper($a_user[$db_translation['login']])' into it.
For example :

```
$foo = strtoupper($a_user[$db_translation['login']]);
$res->bindParam(':acc', $foo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 2):

> use **bindValue()** because bindParam() second arg is a reference
>   like

```
$res->bindValue(':acc', strtoupper($a_user[$db_translation['login']]));
```

> if you want to use **bindParam** then you have to store your statement
>   into one variable and pass that variable as an argument. like.

```
$test = strtoupper($a_user[$db_translation['login']];
$res->bindParam(':acc', $test), PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$param = strtoupper($a_user[$db_translation['login']]);
$res->bindParam(':acc', $param, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```