# Getting Strict Standards Error in Pear folder in Magento

Tags: php, magento, upgrade, pear

I am newbie to Magento Development.

I have an error, when I am trying to update my Magento 1.4.2.1 to Magento 1.7, I am getting Notice of Strict Standards.

I cannot go past those error, except by disabling those errors.

and My Magento is also not upgrading to 1.7,

I think this might be due to the notice which I am disabling.

**The Errors which I am getting are:**

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method Maged_Pear::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in E:\xampp\htdocs\urban\downloader\Maged\Model\Pear.php on line 40

Strict Standards: Non-static method Maged_Pear::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in E:\xampp\htdocs\urban\downloader\Maged\Model\Pear.php on line 40

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR_Command::factory() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in E:\xampp\htdocs\urban\downloader\Maged\Pear.php on line 231

Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in E:\xampp\htdocs\urban\downloader\Maged\Pear.php on line 231

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR_Command::getFrontendObject() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in E:\xampp\htdocs\urban\downloader\pearlib\php\PEAR\Command.php on line 142

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR_Frontend::singleton() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in E:\xampp\htdocs\urban\downloader\pearlib\php\PEAR\Command.php on line 175

Strict Standards: Non-static method Maged_Pear::getInstance() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in E:\xampp\htdocs\urban\downloader\Maged\Model\Pear.php on line 40
```

Comment: Not getting any update, Is there no person in Magento, who can solbe this error and can update my Magento. Please don't give me solution like SSH, as I am using Windows Platform and I have already upgraded the PEAR through Shell Command Line.

Comment: This is more related to hosting environment.So do ask your hosting company for some assistance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 0):

Those are strict warnings, not errors.

You have to disable them in `php.ini` by setting `error_reporting` to not include E_STRICT errors.