# Strict standards not allowing a simple php explode statement?

Tags: php, explode, apc, strict

I'm getting this error:

**Strict Standards**:  Only variables should be passed by reference in **/home/mydomain/public_html/printshop/upload_2-img-dpi.php** on line **55**

These are lines 49 to 56:

```
if(!is_dir($upload_dir)){
    mkdir($upload_dir, 0777, TRUE);
    chmod($upload_dir, 0777);
}       

    $value = explode(".", $userfile_name); // line 55
    $file_ext = strtolower(array_pop($value));
```

What's wrong? This code was working fine before I got APC installed on my server.

Comment: And what is the line 54?

Comment: I [can't reproduce](http://3v4l.org/I0deH#v431) the error on several PHP versions. Are you sure you're referring to the right file/lines ?

Comment: I just edited my question to include more lines of code. Yes I really am using the right lines/file. Does this have anything to do with error options? Or the fact that APC was just installed on the server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I did this, and it worked:

```
    $value = array();
    $value = explode(".", $userfile_name);
    $file_ext = strtolower(end($value));
```

*shrug*

Comment: [php 6.0 should introduce E_DOESNT_WORK and E_LOLWUT](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=10722135#10722135)