# Strict standards: only variables should be passed by reference - why does this still work and how can I correct it?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to query a database to check if an email is already registered, following submission of user details.

However, I get a "Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference" error with the following code (excerpt):

```
} else  if (isset($_POST['srSubmit']) && $_POST['srEmail']) {

    //check if email already taken
    if ($stmtreg = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT user_email FROM users WHERE user_email = ?")) {
        $stmtreg->bind_param("s", strtolower($_POST['srEmail']));
        $stmtreg->execute();
        $stmtreg->store_result();
        $num_rows = $stmtreg->num_rows();
        $stmtreg->bind_result($email);
        $stmtreg->fetch();
        $stmtreg->close();
    }
```

I have two questions: i) why does the script still work, even with this error? an ii) what is causing it and how do I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: "Strict standards" isn't an error, it's a warning/notice, so that's why it works. They're advisory for best-practices, not "something isn't working". That said, I don't see any passing by reference here - are you sure this matches the line number from the error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a temporary variable for `strtolower($_POST['srEmail'])`, something like:

```
$email = strtolower($_POST['srEmail']);
```

and then pass in `$email` to your `bind_param`. Even though strtolower() returns a string,  PDO cant reference it because it's not a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Can't answer your first question, but here is how you pass by reference:

```
//check if email already taken
if ($stmtreg = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT user_email FROM users WHERE user_email = ?")) {
    $email = strtolower($_POST['srEmail']);
    $stmtreg->bind_param("s", &$email);
    $stmtreg->execute();
    $stmtreg->store_result();
    $num_rows = $stmtreg->num_rows();
    $stmtreg->bind_result($email);
    $stmtreg->fetch();
    $stmtreg->close();
}
```

In order to pass a variable by reference, you need to put an `&` before the variable name (eg `&$email`)

Comment: thanks, that creates a Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed (line 3). Could this be an error elsewhere in my code?

Comment: @alias51, this won't solve your problem. He's answering for a different problem which won't help you in this case. Remove the & from the `$email` being passed into `bind_param` and it'll work OK

Answer (score 0):

Look at this line:

```
$stmtreg->bind_param("s", strtolower($_POST['srEmail']));
```

As [php manual for bind_param](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) says:

```
bool mysqli_stmt::bind_param ( string $types , mixed &$var1 [, mixed &$... ] )
```

This function requires a variable to be passed by reference. While you are not passing a value to it: the result of strtolower function.

To see the difference look at this code:

```
<?php
function foo(&$var)
{
    $var .= "!";
}

$a = "1";
foo($a);
print $a;
print "\n";

$b = "1";
foo(strtolower($b));
print $b;
?>
```

It will print:

```
1!
1
```

$b wasn't modified, because php doesn't have a variable to modify. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

So, save your result to a variable and pass it instead:

```
$email = strtolower($_POST['srEmail']);
$stmtreg->bind_param("s", $email);
```

> "why does the script still work, even with this error?"

Because you just need to substitute the parameter with the value and is not modifying the input variable in bind_param function.

Answer (score 0):

**Q:** Why does this script still work?

Because it's a warning, not really an error.

**Q:** What's causing it?

It's this line causing the error.

```
$stmtreg->bind_param("s", strtolower($_POST['srEmail']));
```

bind_param is expecting a VARIABLE as the second parameter. The `strtolower` function returns a string, not a variable.

**Q:** How do I fix this?

One way to fix this is to assign the return from strtolower to a variable, and then reference the variable in bind_param:

```
$lower_email = strtolower($_POST['srEmail']);
$stmtreg->bind_param("s", $lower_email);
```