# Upgraded server from 5.2 php to 5.4, having errors now

Tags: php

1st error is

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/.sites/143/site2/dispatch.php on line 196

dispatch.php 's line 196 looks like so

```
$table_name = array_pop(split('/',$controller));
```

2nd error is

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/.sites/143/site2/lib/referer.php on line 18

referer.php 's line 18 looks like so

```
$agentInfo = array_pop($db->get('agencies','company_name,enabled',"id='$agent_id'"));
```

3rd error is

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/.sites/143/site2/controllers/step4.php on line 978

step4.php 's line 978 looks like so

```
$info = array_pop($this->db->get_records_by_sql($sql));
```

Comment: Turn those into two lines of code with the code in `array_pop()` being its own line.

Comment: John, that should be the answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848295/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference-error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041225/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference-in-wordpress-wp-i

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788744/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the first one to

```
$r=explode('/',$controller);
$table_name = array_pop($r);
```

and then

```
$q=$db->get('agencies','company_name,enabled',"id='$agent_id'");
$agentInfo = array_pop($q);
```

and

```
$q=$this->db->get_records_by_sql($sql);
$info = array_pop($q);
```

This is because the function `array_pop` returns a reference to a variable, the last array member. note this only as strict warning, not an error.

Comment: Thanks Cole, your fixes worked and also informed me on why it didn't work properly!

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you're passing the return value of the `split()` function to `array_pop()`, but `array_pop()` expects an array to be passed by reference, not a value.

You can verify this by looking at the function description in the documentation for [`array_pop()`](http://php.net/array_pop):

> mixed array_pop ( array **& $array** )

The `&` sign indicates that the function expects an array passed by reference.

You can resolve this issue by using an array variable to store the output of the function. Also, note that [`split()`](http://php.net/split) is deprecated. Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) instead:

```
$array = explode('/', $controller);
$table_name = array_pop($array);
```

Change all the similar occurrences.

Comment: Tried that generates the error

    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$table_name' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/.sites/143/site2/dispatch.php on line 134

I have also tried preg_split and that generates different errors as well :[

Comment: @CanadianCaveman: What error? Did you actually change the code as I suggested?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$table_name' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/.sites/143/site2/dispatch.php on line 134 is the error I get.

Comment: @CanadianCaveman: That's pretty self-explanatory. Add a semicolon at the end of the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Optimal is, you shoud stay with project in version 5.2, in future just use 5.4. You find out this errors, but you can find any other errors in future and it is not good way to eleminate all your errors in project.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the PHP function array_pop() requires a reference to a variable instead of a value. See the little & next to the $array parameter on this page?

http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-pop.php

You can fix that by using something like this:

```
$data = $this->db->get_records_by_sql($sql);
$info = array_pop($data);
```