# Using ucwords and explode to ignore hyphens and capitalise words in php

Tags: php, echo, explode, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I am using this php code

```
    <title>Web Design <?php
    echo ucwords(array_shift(explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])));
    ?>, Website Design</title>
```

to grab the subdomain (subdomain.domain.co.uk) which works great
However -
 I want it to ignore the hyphen and capitalise the words for hyphenated subdomains
i.e. sub-domain.domain.co.uk  => Sub Domain

What do I have to alter my code to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str_replace('-', ' ', $subdomain)` before calling `ucwords` to replace `-` with a space. For example:

```
<?php
$subdomain = array_shift(explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));
echo ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $subdomain));
?>
```

Comment: Just thought- one more thing - what would I have to change it to for the result to be 1) all lower case and without hyphens and 2) also all lower case and with hyphens?

Comment: `strtolower` will convert a string to all lower case. Using the example above: 1) `echo strtolower(str_replace('-', ' ', $subdomain));` and 2) `echo strtolower($subdomain);`

Comment: I am getting this error now Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/bluesky1/public_html/middlesex/index.php on line 93

Comment: Assign `explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])` to a variable and then pass that variable into `array_shift()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference.

Answer (score 0):

Tried `str_replace` ?

```
<?php
  $domain = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
  $domain = explode( ".", $domain ); // split domain by comma
  $domain = array_shift( $domain ); // shift an element off the begginning of array
  $domain = str_replace( "-", " ", $domain ); // replace all occureance of '-' to space
  $domain = ucwords( $domain ); // uppercase the first character of words

  echo $domain;
?>
```