# Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference - Registration Form

Tags: php, variables, reference, registration

I'm trying to get a registration form to work and when I put in my user, pw and email I get 3 lines of error.

```
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':name', $user->get("name")); ERROR HERE
    $query->bindParam(':email', $user->get("email")); ERROR HERE
    $query->bindParam(':pw', $user->get("password")); ERROR HERE
    try {
        $out = $query->execute();
    } catch (Exception $e){
        $out = false;
    }
    return $out;
```

Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\XXX\classes\User_Table.class.php on line 13

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the sidebar of related questions.

Comment: Try not only to read error message, but also to _understand_ it.

Comment: I've been stuck on it for a good hour or so, Im still learning PHP so  this is all very new for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query->bindParam(':name', $user->get("name")); //ERROR HERE
```

You must put the data into a variable, before passing it to the function, requiring a reference as a parameter. Like this:

```
$variable = $user->get("name");
$query->bindParam(':name', $variable); //NO ERROR HERE
```

Here is the explanation, what can be passed by reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: Hey user4035, that totally worked for me! Thanks alot appreciate it.