# Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in..

Tags: php, image, standards, strict

I am receiving an error when I attempt to upload an image. The image is always uploaded, but after every upload I receive this error:

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in
>   /filemanager/afmlib.php on line 57

Line 57 in my filemanager is:

```
 function AFM_fileExt($filename)
 {
  return strtolower(end(explode('.', $filename)));////THIS IS LINE: 57
 }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: rewrite it without trying to make the code in one line at any cost?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 2):

Why not let PHP do the work:

```
function AFM_fileExt($filename) {
    return strtolower(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
}
```

For the sake of completeness, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2354755/2765666) gives a good explanation of how the error arises. It's because [`end(array &$array)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) uses a reference - note the ampersand in the declaration.

Answer (score -1):

BTW your codes works for me.

And i dont know about it works but try this one

```
function AFM_fileExt($filename)
{
    $arr = explode('.', $filename);
    return strtolower(end($arr));
}
```