# email validation 'Error : Strict Standards' or any best way to validate email?

Tags: php, email-validation, strict

I have a script that will validate an email address & I think this is the only **solution** to validate emails on form submission? I end up with this script

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email']))

{
    $email = $_POST['email'];  

    if (strpos($email, '@')) 
    {
        $first = end(explode("@", $email));

        if(checkdnsrr($first, 'MX')) 
        {
            $validate = 'Valid email.';
        }
        else 
        {
            $validate = 'Invalid email.';   
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $validate = 'Invalid email.';
    }

    echo $validate;
}
?>  
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

It runs correctly but I have this error `Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference`.

Is there any way to remove the **ERROR**? and **IMPROVE** the code? Is there any *email validation* so far that is really validate emails?

Comment: did you resolved your problem

Comment: What is your PHP version?

Comment: do u want help on this still

Comment: mail me about your problem briefly to my email @venkatakrishnabtech@gmail.com

Comment: Why are you doing your own validation? Why not use a third-party validation API like LeadSpend.com?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reson is, `end(explode("@", $email));` function causes the error, `end()` needs a reference,  for that you can try using the below code,

```
$EmailArray = explode("@", $email);
$first = end($EmailArray);
```

`mixed end ( array &$array )`

`end()` advances array's internal pointer to the last element, and returns its value.

**Parameter:**

*array*:   This array is passed by reference because it is modified by the function. This means you must pass it a real variable and not a function returning an array because only actual variables may be passed by reference.

*Return Values:* Returns the value of the last element or FALSE for empty array.

Comment: $EmailArray = explode("@", $email);
$first = end($EmailArray); I have updated myanswer, can you try

Comment: seems that you need to pass it on another variable. yes that helps my problem :)

Comment: do you want the help?

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email']))

{
    $email = $_POST['email'];  

    if (strpos($email, '@')) 
    {
        $first = explode("@", $email);

        $validate = checkdnsrr($first[1], 'MX') ? 'Valid email.' : 'Invalid email.';
    }
    else
    {
        $validate = 'Invalid email.';
    }

    echo $validate;
}
?>  
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like below as a example

```
 <?php

    function domain_exists($email, $record = 'MX'){
        list($user, $domain) = explode('@', $email);
        return checkdnsrr($domain, $record);
    }
    if(isset($_POST['email'])){
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        if(domain_exists($email)) {
            echo('This MX records exists; I will accept this email as valid.');
        }
        else {
            echo('No MX record exists;  Invalid email.');
        }
    }
    ?>
```

But, this isn't reliable. dns isn't reliable in general. It's best-effort. It can also take a long time when an invalid domain is provided, so you need to consider a potential DOS of your system if someone hammers your script with a lot of invalid/offline domains.

In (little known) fact, domains don't even need to have an MX record for mail to be delivered. Mail delivery is supposed to fall back to using the A record for the host specified. That may not really happen much these days, but in theory..

so you can validate your email with preg match like

```
 //$email = "abc123@lolhaha"; // Invalid email address 
    $email = "somebody@somesite.com"; // Valid email address 

    $regex = '/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/'; 

    if (preg_match($regex, $email)) {
         echo $email . " is a valid email. We can accept it.";
    } else { 
         echo $email . " is an invalid email. Please try again.";
    }
```

Comment: regex can't validate email it's just validating the input.