# Strict Standards message on php array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, iterator

I currently am getting the following error message when splitting out array values by character: **Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference**

This is my array:

```
array(6) { [0]=> string(8) "2390:SS0" [1]=> string(8) "2391:SS1" [2]=> string(9) "2392:SS11" [3]=> string(7) "250:BS1" [4]=> string(8) "251:BS10" [5]=> string(8) "252:BS11" }
```

This is my php:

```
foreach ($postcodes as $key => $value)
{
  $postcode_ids     = current(explode(':', $value));
  $postcode         = next(explode(':', $value));
}
```

The notice seems to appear on the next line? Any ideas or pointer would be great. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

next() modifies the array that you pass in. It is passed by reference. Therefore you cannot use

```
next( [expression] );
```

but only

```
next( [variable] );
```

To simplify your code, replace

```
 $postcode_ids     = current(explode(':', $value));
 $postcode         = next(explode(':', $value));
```

with

```
 list($postcode_ids, $postcode) = explode(':', $value);
```

Comment: Im not sure how I would split the value of the array, if I can use next?

Comment: Fantastic, works great. I have never seen this array function before it will come in very handy.