# Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference & Strict Standards: Non-static method

Tags: php, standards, strict

I've Just moved over to a new host and I'm getting these errors:

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/---/public_html/dl/index.php on line 34**

This is what is on line 34:

```
echo '<title>'.str_replace('%20', ' ', end(array_filter(explode("/", $_GET['dir'])))).' | PlayWAP.Mobi</title>';**
```

And then I'm getting this as well:

> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/---/public_html/dl/id.php on line 403**

Please can you help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 1):

The function `end()` does expect a variable, not a function result, as is documented on php.net: http://php.net/end

The PEAR class does not define it's method `isError()` as static, so you are not allowed to call it like this: `PEAR::isError($foo)`.

Both errors can be disabled by setting a less strict error level, but they are signs of a codebase getting older and needing a refresh. Without fixing these errors (and not just silencing the error output), you might be unable to use your website on a new PHP installation in some years.