# Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\wamp\www\lions\admin\UploadmemberHandler.php on line 3

Tags: php, variables, strict

I'm getting this error:

> Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\wamp\www\lions\admin\UploadmemberHandler.php on line 3

Code:

```
$extension1 = end(explode(".", $_FILES["addmemberFile"]["name"]));
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: welcome to SO. First read how to post questions in SO.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: what is in `$_FILES["addmemberFile"]["name"])` ?

Comment: Smallest script in the world.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`end()`](http://php.net/end) expects its parameter to be passed by reference, and in PHP, [only variables can be passed by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php). You can easily fix this by storing the array in a variable and calling `end()` with that.

```
$arr = explode(".", $_FILES["addmemberFile"]["name"]);
$extension1 = end($arr);
```

Even better, use the function which is specifically built for retrieving the file extension, [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/pathinfo):

```
$extension1 = pathinfo($_FILES["addmemberFile"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```