# Strict standards error?

Tags: php

The code below was working correctly a time ago, however, when I tried to use it now, it says that there is an error in this line :

```
 $date1 = new DateTime(array_shift(array_values($array_of_dates)));
```

The error says :

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home/...
```

Below is my code :

```
public function get_user_weeks($user_id,$getdays = NULL,$before_num_days = NULL) {

$weeks_between =0;
$pgql = mysql_query("SELECT at_time FROM users WHERE track_id='$user_id' ORDER BY at_time ASC");
$array_of_dates = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($pgql, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $array_of_dates[] = $row['at_time'];
}

$date1 = new DateTime(array_shift(array_values($array_of_dates)));
 if ($before_num_days==NULL) {
$date2 = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d h:m:s")); }
else {



    $date2 = date("Y-m-d h:m:s");
    $date2 = strtotime('+'.$before_num_days.' day', strtotime($date2));
    $date2 = date('Y-m-d h:m:s',$date2);
    $date2 = new DateTime($date2);

    }
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
if(NULL == $getdays) {
$weeks_between = (($interval->d) + (30.5 * $interval->m) + (365 * $interval->y))/7; }
else {
$weeks_between = (($interval->d) + (30.5 * $interval->m) + (365 * $interval->y));
    }

return $weeks_between;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is triggered by [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/array_shift), because it needs a variable, not a value, as an argument.

```
$values = array_values($array_of_dates);
$value  = array_shift($values);
$date1  = new DateTime($value);
```

---

Also, please note that MySQL extension is officially deprecated one. Use `MySQLi` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: This is the right answer, thankyou. I will accept it in  10 min

Answer (score 1):

[array_shift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) takes a reference, so you need to change your code like this:

```
$values = array_values($array_of_dates);
$values = array_shift($values);
$date1 = new DateTime($values);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because a reference is returned... In such case, assign that to a variable and overcome this issue.

You can do like this...

```
$date1 = new DateTime($dt=array_shift(array_values($array_of_dates))); //Check the variable $dt ;)
```