# Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in m_auth

Tags: php, oop

I am working on a login system for a project using MVC programming and ran into this error.  Here is the code, the problem line is #31

This login system is a tutorial, I have been working through it exactly as is.  I've read there are some version issues with PHP 5?  Not sure, hopefully somebody could assist me.

Problem line:

```
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, md5($pass . $this->salt));
```

Code:

```
<?php

/*
    Authorization Class
    deal with auth tasks
*/

class Auth
{
private $salt = 'j4H9?s0d';

/*
    Constructor
*/
function __construct()
{
}

/*
    Functions

*/
function validateLogin($user, $pass)
{
    // access db
    global $Database;

    // create query
    if ($stmt = $Database->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?"))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, md5($pass . $this->salt));
        $stmt->execute;
        $stmt->store_result();

        // check for num rows
        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0)
        {
            // success
            $stmt->close();
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            // failure
            $stmt->close();
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        die("ERROR: Could not prepare MySQLi statement.");
    }
}

function checkLoginStatus()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

function logout()
{
    session_destroy();
    session_start();
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Comment: Please don't use MD5 for hashing passwords. PHP 5.5+ has [password API](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.password.php) for that and if that's not an option, you can use `crypt()` with blowfish algorithm as a fallback. Also, **dont use global variable** for propagating DB connection. Instead you should use something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11369679/727208 (the approch can be easily addopted to work with MySQLi). And if that code of yours comes from some tutorial - find a different tutorial, ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

`bind_param`'s params are references to variables.  You can't use `md5()` there.  You need to save it to a variable first.

```
$userPass = md5($pass . $this->salt);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $userPass);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the 3rd parameter is the result of a function call:

`md5($pass . $this->salt)`

You need to save that value to a variable before passing it to `bind_param` so that it can be passed by reference.

**Example:**

```
$password = md5($pass . $this->salt);  
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $password);
```

Also, **[don't use md5 to hash passwords](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Add parenthesis:

```
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, (md5($pass . $this->salt)));
```

Answer (score 0):

This was likely fixed in PHP 5.4 as part of [Function Array Dereferencing (FAD)](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing) ([revision 300266](http://svn.php.net/viewvc?view=revision&revision=300266)).

Alternatively as workaround try adding extra brackets, e.g.

```
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, (md5($pass . $this->salt)));
```

which would dereference the method/function return,
[see: (<5.6) Occasionally significant parentheses](http://phpsadness.com/sad/51).