# Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference (qdig gallery)

Tags: php, standards

The code from Qdig Gallery is:

```
$excl_imgs[] = end($logo_arrray = explode('/', $header['css_logo_url']));
$excl_imgs[] = end($bg_img_array = explode('/', $header['css_bg_img_url']));
```

which gives the above error (Strict Standards).

How do I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this instead and your error should go away:

```
$logo_arrray = explode('/', $header['css_logo_url']);
$bg_img_array = explode('/', $header['css_bg_img_url']);

$excl_imgs[] = end($logo_arrray);
$excl_imgs[] = end($bg_img_array);
```

You should always try and fix any Strict Standards warning and not just hide them.

Answer (score 0):

I liked to do this to have my code in one line, you can write this method and use `end_legacy` instead of end when want to use end like that.

```
 function end_legacy($arr){
   if (empty($arr))return false;
   if ( PHP_VERSION_ID > 50400) {
     $count = count($arr);
     $arr = array_values($arr);
     return $arr[ $count-1 ];
   }
   return end($arr);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can disable this error and it should be ok. Here's a guide https://www.flexicontent.org/site-content/70-developer-api-field-plugins/285-disabling-php-strict-standards-warning-on-development-servers.html 
Hope it helps.

Comment: You shouldn't hide Strict Standards warnings, good practice is to actually fix what caused the warning in the first place.