# PHP - bind_param throwing the warning for INSERT prepare statement

Tags: php

When I am trying to insert row with below snippet, it throwing the strict standard warning for   **$user_info_do->get_first_name()** where user_info_do is class with member variable first_name.

`ERROR: Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference`

```
$query = "INSERT INTO user_info ( first_name ) VALUES (?);";

if( !($query_stmt = $this->m_db_connection->prepare($query))) {         
   return;
}

if( !$query_stmt->bind_param("s", $user_info_do->get_first_name() ) {
   return;
}
```

Please help me what could be the reason here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysqli : Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23843383/mysqli-strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `bind_param` binds *variables* to a prepared statements (their values will be extracted when statements are sent to DB), and you attempt to pass a *value* (result of `$user_info_do->get_first_name()`) into it. That's why you get an error: values cannot be passed by reference.

Change your code into something like...

```
$firstName = $user_info_do->get_first_name();
if( !$query_stmt->bind_param("s", $firstName ) ) {
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$query_stmt->bind_param` requires all params to be passed by reference, so you can't pass function's return value directly (without assigning it to a variable first, that is).

[mysqli : Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23843383/mysqli-strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Comment: It's not a good practice copying an answer word-to-word. If this guestion is a duplicate, just ask to close it.

Comment: I have added a link to the original answer. So its not a copy at all.