# Format of $_POST variables into prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql

This is probably a dumb question but if i am inserting data using MySQLi and prepared statements.

Is it possible to put in one line different conditions?

For example if text are `Active` change to `Inactive` and if text are `Inactive` change to `Active`. Is it possible to do in only one line?

```
$Status = ($_POST['status'] == "Inactive" ? "Inactive" : "Active");
```

Comment: Are you doing anything else in that query, or just toggling the active/inactive? Show your query, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're doing is toggling the status between `Active` and `Inactive`, then you can do it in a single query, using `CASE WHEN`.

```sql
UPDATE myTable
SET status = (CASE WHEN status = 'Inactive' THEN 'Active' 
                   ELSE 'Inactive' 
              END)

WHERE id = ?
```

Comment: You can also use the `IF()` function which is often shorter: `IF(status='Inactive','Active','Inactive')`.

Comment: @Qirel thanks. I think is better to do this condicional with the update.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the following should be legal:

```
$Status = ($_POST['status'] == "Inactive" ? "Inactive" : "Active");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $Status);
```

```
$stmt->bind_param("s", ($_POST['status'] == "Inactive" ? "Inactive" : "Active"));
```

> WARNING : this 2nd version yields the **"Only variables should be passed by reference"** strict standards warning.  Consider your situation carefully when choosing this approach.

---

... But note that your expression,

```
($_POST['status'] == "Inactive" ? "Inactive" : "Active")
```

will yield `Inactive` when `$_POST['status']` is already `Inactive`, which is the opposite of the desired behavior you described in your question.  I believe you want:

```
($_POST['status'] == "Inactive" ? "Active" : "Inactive")
```

---

**EDIT 1**

Regarding your comment question, "but, not's possible to put something else for example: `if ($_POST['status'] == 'Inactive'){ $Status = ($_POST['status'] == "Inactive" ? "Inactive" : "Active"); else ...`", something like that is legal, but doesn't make too much sense.  That literally is the same thing as:

```
if ($_POST['status'] == 'Inactive') {
    if ($_POST['status'] == "Inactive") {
        $Status = "Inactive";
    } else {
        $Status = "Active";
    } else {
        ...
}
```

Comment: Can I put this with if else statement for example in the same line?

Comment: @GuifIf : if I understand your question correctly, no : PHP will not evaluate an `if ... else` statement down to a value; `bind_param()` (like all functions) is expecting a set of values for its parameter list, so you can only use variables that contain a value or expressions that evaluate to a value

Comment: but, not's possible to put something else for example: ```if ($_POST['status'] == 'Inactive'){ $Status = ($_POST['status'] == "Inactive" ? "Inactive" : "Active"); else.```..

Comment: Note that your second snippet would yield warnings - "*Only variables should be passed by reference*" - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23843383/mysqli-strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference?rq=1

Comment: @GuifIf : the ternary operator (`condition ? true-result : false-result`) is already a kind of `if ... else` statement; it doesn't make much sense to combine an `if ... else` with a ternary evaluation the way that you have; I will edit my answer to illustrate ...

Comment: @Qirel : thanks!  I've added a cautionary note to that effect