# Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference PHP Shopping Cart

Tags: php, mysql, shopping-cart

i'm currently in the process of creating a PHP shopping cart but keep i'm stuck with the error "Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference  PHP Shopping Cart". I've researched the error, found many different explanations as to why this is happening. I can't seem to resolve the issue.  Any help would be much appreciated. Please see my code below.

```
  $img=mysql_real_escape_string(end(explode('/',$_POST['img'])));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break up your code instead of doing it all at once, like so:

```
$imgArr = explode('/',$_POST['img']);
$img = end($imgArr);
$imgEscaped = mysql_real_escape_string($img);
```

The reason why is that [end()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) expects a **variable** to be passed by reference, and so you need to assign your explode() to an intermediate variable first.