# PHP error: Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php

I'm using [BlueImp jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) with database integration, adapting the [script found here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/PHP-MySQL-database-integration).

I changed a bit the `handle_file_upload()` method like this:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO '.$this->options['db_table'].' (`path`, `type`, `tab`, `item`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';
$query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$query->bind_param(
    'ssii',
    $path = $this->options['upload_url'] . $file->name,
    $file->type,
    $file->tab,
    $file->item
);
```

but, on the line `$path = $this->options['upload_url'] . $file->name`, I have a `Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference` error

Well, I have no idea how to change this...

I tried to look at other answers, but they don't fit into my case: please any help? Thanks

Comment: Create a new variable `$x = $this->options['upload_url'] . $file->name` and then bind `$x` as `path`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is passed by reference the variable needs to exist before binding

```
 $path = $this->options['upload_url'] . $file->name;
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO '.$this->options['db_table'].' (`path`, `type`, `tab`, `item`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $query->bind_param(
        'ssii',
        $path,
        $file->type,
        $file->tab,
        $file->item
    );
```

Comment: Thanks, I should be a little bit tired :-)... I was trying something like `$tmp = $this->options['upload_url']  . $file->name;` ... `$path = $tmp` and it didn't work: I thought the problem was in the dot-chain, not in the assignment

Answer (score 2):

This should work...

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO '.$this->options['db_table'].' (`path`, `type`, `tab`, `item`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';
$query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$p = $this->options['upload_url'] . $file->name;
$query->bind_param(
    'ssii',
    $p,
    $file->type,
    $file->tab,
    $file->item
);
```

You were setting $path's value in the parameter binding. So it wouldn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

Read more here: [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO '.$this->options['db_table'].' (`path`, `type`, `tab`, `item`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';
$query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$upload_url = $this->options['upload_url']  . $file->name;
$query->bind_param(
    'ssii',
    $path = $upload_url,
    $file->type,
    $file->tab,
    $file->item
);
```