# While loop: only Variables can be passed by reference error

Tags: php

I am running into a "Only variables should be passed by reference" error, because on the code I am using there is a line that does not put the explode() result into a variable. As required when using strict PHP standards.

However because the explode() function is used in a While loop I can't think of a appropriate solution.

My code looks like

```
    function user_exists($username) {
    rewind($this->fp);
        while(!feof($this->fp) && trim($lusername = array_shift(explode(":",$line = rtrim(fgets($this->fp)))))) {
            if($lusername == $username)
                return 1;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: You're trying to cram way too much into one single line there, and as a result, not only is it extremely hard to read, it is error-prone, as you can see. Break things up. Set temporary variables and then use them in the while loop instead. Also you're not even using `$line` anywhere (unless this isn't the whole code for this method), so that could be eliminated.

Comment: Thanks @Mike. Any suggestions on how to best break the code up?
I've tried:
$temps = explode(":",rtrim(fgets($this->fp)));
            while(!feof($this->fp) && trim($lusername = array_shift($temps))) {}

This does solve the reference error, but breaks the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe you need to sit back and break your code apart a bit and take a look at what is happening.

First, condition is while `!feof($this->fp)`

From the [manual](http://php.net/feof):

> feof — Tests for end-of-file on a file pointer

One thing you will notice here is that `feof()` is only a test which returns `true` or `false`. It does **not** advance the pointer position while looping over, so while using this function, somewhere else in your while loop there needs to be something that advances the pointer or else you will have an infinite loop.

Second condition is:

```
trim($lusername = array_shift(explode(":",$line = rtrim(fgets($this->fp)))))
```

First function from left to right is [trim()](http://php.net/trim), which returns a `string`. From our handy dandy [comparison table](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) we see that when doing `if ((String) $var)` it evaluates to `false` if and only if the string is empty (`""`) or the number zero as a string (`"0"`), otherwise it returns `true`. Personally I tend to really hate using `if ((String) $var)` (first because it's slightly unclear to newbies unless you know your comparison table well and second because 99% of the time people are doing that they are actually checking for string length, in which case I would want it to return `true` for the string `"0"`). So assuming that you don't need it to return `false` for `"0"` we could change this to `strlen($var) > 0` and then manipulate the variable within the loop. That should greatly simplify things here.

So now we have:

```
while (!feof($this->fp) && strlen($var) > 0) { /*...*/ }
```

This will loop over until either we are at the end of the file or `$var` is an empty line. Everything else can be offloaded into the body of the `while` loop, so it is much easier to break apart.

So this is what we have now:

```
$line = rtrim(fgets($this->fp));
$lusername = array_shift(explode(":",$line)));
```

Uh-oh! There's that "nasty" error:

> **Strict Standards:** Only variables should be passed by reference in **/path/to/file.php** on line **x**.

So we can see from here, the part producing the error is not `explode()`, but `array_shift()`. See also: [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

What this means is that since `array_shift()` modifies the array, it requires it to be by reference. Since you are not passing an actual variable but instead the result of a function, PHP is unable to modify it.  It's similar to doing something like `function($var) = 3;`. Of course you can't do that. Instead you need to save the value to a temporary variable. So now we have:

```
$line = rtrim(fgets($this->fp));
$split = explode(":",$line);
$lusername = array_shift($split);
```

Woo hoo! No more warning message.

So putting this together, we now have:

```
while (!feof($this->fp) && strlen($lusername) > 0) {
    $line = rtrim(fgets($this->fp));
    $split = explode(":",$line);
    $lusername = array_shift($split);
    if($lusername == $username) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Also, as mentioned earlier, the [`fgets()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) will advance the pointer, which allows the `!feof($this->fp)` part in the `while` statement to vary.