# How to get the last item of a nested array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 191
            [range] => today
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 190
            [range] => today
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 189
            [range] => in last week
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 180
            [range] => in last week
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 170
            [range] => in last week                  <- this
        )
)
*/
```

I'm trying to get the vale of `range` which is last item. in this case it is `in last week`. Here is my code:

```
foreach ( $results as $item ) {
    $last_range_item = $item[range];
}
```

My approach should work, but there is a lot of useless processes and overwriting. So is there any better way?

Comment: use `array_column($arr, 'range')`. using this you can do it. or use `echo $result[count($result)-1]['range']`.

Comment: @FrayneKonok It isn't just containing the last one.

Comment: see updated comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the last range using different ways.

```
 1. echo $result[count($result)-1]['range'];
 2. $new = array_column($arr, 'range'); echo $new[count($new)-1];
 3. and so on....
```

Comment: Check this and let me know is it works for you or not. If not then i have to test it.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple way:

```
echo end(end($arr));
```

Comment: @Stack do it in steps `$temp = end($results);     
 echo end($temp);`

Comment: @Stack [Take a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference). You can also suppress error message using `@` operator, but thats not nice work-around tho.