# PHP only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php, mysql, sockets

I was setting up a PHP server when this error came up:

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xamp\htdocs\Xce Source\Source\Extra\Xce.php on line 75
>   PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xamp\htdocs\Xce Source\Source\Extra\Xce.php on line 75

This is the line 75:

```
$ready = socket_select($read, $w = null, $e = null, $t = 0);
```

What do I need to change? I always have this problem with exactly this same code

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. -1, don't take it the wrong way. A down vote is how we indicate a content problem around here; improve your formatting and code sample and I (or someone will) gladly revert it. Good luck with your code!

Comment: your grammar? no seriously remove the assignment `$w = null` and pass just the variable `$w` or `null`  or in the case this is a copy and paste error and you don't want those last 3 remove them.

Comment: actually `null` wont work in this case from the PHP documents site `Due a limitation in the current Zend Engine it is not possible to pass a constant modifier like NULL directly as a parameter to a function which expects this parameter to be passed by reference`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$ready = socket_select($read, $w = null, $e = null, $t = 0);` use this:

```
$w = null;
$e = null;
$t = 0;

$ready = socket_select($read, $w, $e, $t);
```

When you do something like this `$w = null` as a function parameter, you are actually passing `null`, not a reference to the `$w` variable. `socket_select` requires references as parameters to work.

Comment: Thank you ;3 sorry for bothering with a silly question ;c

Answer (score 1):

As said in the documentation [there](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php), it should be:

```
$w = null; 
$e = null; 
$t = 0; 
$ready = socket_select($read, $w, $e, $t)
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry i am new in this and i didn't wanted to screw the code ;D

Comment: No problem @TaroYamada :) Keep something in mind: The documentation is the bible when coding :D  Don't forget to accept the answer and vote if my answer helped. Have a nice day/night.