# How do I fix the error "Only variables should be passed in by reference"?

Tags: php, explode

I have the following code.

```
$final = array();
$search_for = '<POPULARITY URL';
$part = file_get_contents_curl('http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url='.trim($domain));

$str = explode($search_for, $part); //ERROR HAPPENS HERE//
$str = array_shift(explode('"/>', $str[1]));
$str = explode('TEXT="', $str);
$str[1] = str_replace('" SOURCE="panel',"",$str[1]);
preg_match('#<COUNTRY CODE="(.*?)" NAME="(.*?)" RANK="(.*?)"#si', $part, $c);
$final['global_rank'] = $str[1];
$final['country_name'] = $c[2];
$final['country_rank'] = $c[3];
return $final;
```

I can't seem to get this to work out without getting this error. 
    "Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference"

Comment: put the content of `explode('"/>', $str[1])` in a variable, and pass that to `array_shift`

Comment: Check out this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354609/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference

Comment: do var_dump ($part);   What is your output??

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your dealing with XML as the output there which you can parse with php quite easily to get a node that you are looking for or loop through to get.

Could do this with PHP or Jquery there are means to parse xml 
https://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_xml_simplexml_read.asp
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

hope this helps.